# When translating to English, how to preserve the emphasized part?

Tags: translation

Consider the following sentence.

> この地域**には**夜に星が見える。

Here, には emphasizes the この地域.

If I translate it to English as follows,

> The stars are visible at night in this area.

the nuance of emphasizing "this area" is not preserved, is it?

So, how to preserve such an emphasized part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a subtle difference, but I feel that the below is arguably a more suitable translation given the "では" particle used, which can indicate that in other areas the stars are not visible.

> In this area, the stars are visible at night.

Answer (score 4):

First, に is not the right particle here. This sentence should be:

> この地域**で**は夜に星が見える。

Second, this は is a plain old topic marker. この地域 is topicalized, but not emphasized (at least strongly) by は, unless it's pronounced in an unusual way. You may have seen an answer ([like this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/8270/5010)) which states this kind of は is "emphasis", but that may be a bit misleading.

Your translation seems already perfect to me.