# Genki pg 305, [day of the week] NI vs [day of the week] WA

Tags: grammar

On page 305 of Genki , you can see that Mary starts off each paragraph with a day of the week and the particle that follows is different. Any reason why friday is listed w/ NI vs the other days that all have WA? Could you replace the WAs with NI?

The text goes as follows:

> **金曜日に**日本人のともだちとこうえんにいきました。こうえんでともだちとはなしました。それから、レストランへいきました。たくさんたべました。
>
> **土曜日は**一人でおてらへいきました。たくさんみせがありました。みせでおまんじゅうをかいました。
>
> **日曜日は**おそくおきました。おかあさんもおそくおきました。わたしはあさテレビをみました。それから、おかあさんとひるごはんをたべました。ごごは日本語をべんきょうしました。本もよみました。

Comment: For the benefit of those that don't have the text, can you please include the sentences you are asking about?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8269/5010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

土曜日 and 日曜日 are used with は because she is changing the topic to those days respectively. That is, since she was talking about the day before in the *previous* paragraph, she is now changing the topic to talk about what she is doing on Saturday (or Sunday) in the current paragraph.

Using に with them wouldn't be wrong, but it sounds better with は in this context because she's listing off the days in order and then dedicates a paragraph to describing what she did. If only に were used, the days wouldn't sound as important.

She also could have used は with 金曜日, but it doesn't matter as much as the others because she wasn't talking about anything before, so there's no need to emphasize 金曜日.

Comment: What a clear answer！！ ありがとう！